# The following classes could not be instantiated android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, material-design

I am using Coordinator Layout inside the Drawer Layout. I want to show a auto hide toolbar and use movie poster in it, which will collapse when movie details are scrolled. My app also uses a drawer layout. Here is my Layout XML `activity_coordinator_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.inov8.falconpayconsumer.activities.MovieInfo">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/header_layout2"
                layout="@layout/header" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/sub_header"
            layout="@layout/subheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       tools:context="com.inov8.falconpayconsumer.activities.bookme.MovieDetailsActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:scaleType="matrix"
                    android:src="@drawable/gods_of_egypt"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        layout="@layout/drawer_layout_list" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If it is the problem in the default theme of the application them it is `<style name="My_App_Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />`
In manifest I am using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

and Here is the complete Error shown when drawing this layout

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:     - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)    
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at 
android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:182)   at 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:176)   at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
```

Comment: `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.` - Are you using `Theme.AppCompat` as the parent of your `AppTheme`?

Comment: I am using this <style name="My_App_Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

Comment: Unless `AppTheme`'s parent is also a `Theme.AppCompat` theme, you need to remove `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from the layout, and the `<activity>` in the manifest, if it's there.

Comment: I have done it but it didn't worked, here is the error log when running the application, the app crashes to this activity

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inov8.upayments.mfs/com.inov8.falconpayconsumer.activities.bookme.MovieDetailsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: That's a different error. Please edit your question to provide logcat output. Please don't put it in comments. Does your `Activity` extend `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: that fixed the issue, but now the coordinator layout takes the whole screen, event changing height to wrap content, the linear layout above in not shown

Comment: Change the `CoordinatorLayout`'s `layout_height` to `0dp`, and set its `layout_weight` to `1`.

Comment: done but nothing happened :(

Comment: no text shown for textView inside nestedScrollView

Comment: Oh, I misread your layout. You need to put everything that is the main content into one `ViewGroup`. So put the `CoordinatorLayout` and the `LinearLayout` above it into another vertically-oriented `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one.

> classes could not be instantiated
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

you have add this dependecies in your gradle file.

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

and for second thing .

> IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or
>   descendant)

All you need to do is add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to your application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: I think com.android.support:design:22.2.0 includes reciclerView